# how to include custom js file at the most bottom in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have written some code in my custom.js file and register in the controller.php file as:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $this->registerScripts();
}

public function registerScripts(){
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(
        Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/js/custom.js',CClientScript::POS_END
    );
}
```

When I check at the source code, I saw that `custom.js` file included before `jquery-ui.min.js` at the bottom i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/decksgo_new/js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/decksgo_new/assets/dca3e5d/jui/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

But I want custom.js should be included after `jquery-ui.min.js` file. How I can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register the file as you have done

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(
    Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/js/custom.js',CClientScript::POS_END
);
```

In a view, or the layout and it will be registered after JQuery. That code looks to be in your CController and will be called before the other files subsequently.